# Comparing hashed password with salt always fails

Tags: c#, .net

I saw multiple questions about password hashing and salt but they all seem to fail for me. I use this function to hash/salt it and then put it to database:

```
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        byte[] salt;
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[16]);
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordTextbox.Password, salt, 10000);
        byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
        byte[] hashBytes = new byte[36];
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, 16, 20);
        string savedPasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        return savedPasswordHash;
    }
```

and then I try to compare it with user input using this function:

```
    public static void UnhashPassword(string hashedPassword, string hashedPasswordFromDatabase)
    {
        byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPasswordFromDatabase);
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(hashedPassword, salt, 10000);
        byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            if (hashBytes[i + 16] != hash[i])
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    }
```

the second function always throws exception. Not sure what is the reason since this answer seemed to work for everybody in other question.

Comment: Two things: 1 you pass a `password` into your first function and never use it. 2) the way to check the password matches is to hash the provided password in exactly the same way as the original and see if you get the same results. I'm not sure if you've got the wrong end of the stick here but your password name of "unhashPassword" suggests you have. You can't unhash a password. Hashing is one way process (and that is the whole point - you can't get a password back from a hash).

Comment: @Chris: note that, while the naming of the second method is misleading, the code in that method is actually doing exactly what you describe in your #2 point (and in fact, when presented with correct data, works fine...see below).

Comment: Please update your question, with what type of Exception you are getting and on what line. Apart from what @PeterDuniho already wrote you should't really be using your own encryption in real projects. I would advise you to look into the MembershipProvider class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Igor: presumably the exception being thrown is `UnauthorizedAccessException`, i.e. the one that method explicitly throws when the password fails validation. As for _"using your own encryption"_, while that advice is generally good, it's not clear to me the OP is in violation of it. That advice mainly refers to actually _implementing_ encryption. The OP's code correctly delegates all actual encryption tasks to the framework. It's even better if one can avoid the question altogether and use a library that manages the passwords start-to-finish, but that might not be possible for the OP.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: The OP really should use better names then. To me that second method is operating on an input parameter called `hashedPassword`. I naturally assumed that this contained the hashed password, not the unhashed password. Giving us code with not just bad but actually misleading names doesn't help us understand things and anybody could be forgiven for not correctly guessing what the OP meant. And probably doesn't help the OP understand what they are doing either.

Comment: @Chris: _"The OP really should use better names then"_ -- no disagreement there. But often, inexperience and/or poor coding habits go hand in hand with needing help from others. Fortunately, good names are irrelevant to the actual working of the code. Having seen enough code with poor names (or in some cases, just foreign names I don't comprehend), I've gotten used to seeing past the names for what the code actually _does_. It's a skill I've found very handy from time to time. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I commend your patience. :)

Comment: I was using hashed password as a parameter.. that was the problem. Anyway thank you all for help, and sorry for bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure what is wrong. However, the following code example *does* work exactly as expected (i.e. the value of `result` is `true` after it's been initialized by the call to `ValidatePassword()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string password = "password";
    string hashedPassword = HashPassword(password);
    bool result = ValidatePassword(password, hashedPassword);
}

static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt;
    new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[16]);
    var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 10000);
    byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
    byte[] hashBytes = new byte[36];
    Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, 16);
    Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, 16, 20);
    string savedPasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    return savedPasswordHash;
}

static bool ValidatePassword(string password, string hashedPasswordFromDatabase)
{
    byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPasswordFromDatabase);
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);
    var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 10000);
    byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (hashBytes[i + 16] != hash[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The only material change between the above and your original code is that the `HashPassword()` method uses the `password` value passed in, rather than `PasswordTextbox.Password`.

Based on that observation, I can only surmise that in your own scenario, you are not really hashing the same password as you are validating later. Whether this is because `PasswordTextbox.Password` never did have the right password, or you are passing a different password later, I can't say.

If the above code example does not adequately point you in the right direction so that you can get your code working, please improve your question so that it includes a good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).